# Scipy LinearOperator With Multiple Inputs

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I need to invert a large, dense matrix which I hoped to use Scipy's `gmres` to do. Fortunately, the dense matrix `A` follows a pattern and I do not need to store the matrix in memory. The `LinearOperator` class allows us to construct an object which acts as the matrix for GMRES and can compute directly the matrix vector product `A*v`. That is, we write a function `mv(v)` which takes as input a vector `v` and returns `mv(v) = A*v`. Then, we can use the `LinearOperator` class to create `A_LinOp = LinearOperator(shape = shape, matvec = mv)`. We can put the linear operator into the Scipy `gmres` command to evaluate the matrix vector products without ever having to fully load `A` into memory.

The documentation for the `LinearOperator` is found here: [`LinearOperator` Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.12.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html).

Here is my problem: to write the routine to compute the matrix vector product `mv(v) = A*v`, I need another input vector `C`. The entries in `A` are of the form `A[i,j] = f(C[i] - C[j])`. So, what I really want is for `mv` to be of two inputs, one fixed vector input `C`, and one variable input `v` which we want to compute `A*v`.

MATLAB has a similar setup, where would write `x = gmres(@(v) mv(v,C),b)` where `b` is the right hand side of the problem `Ax = b`, , and `mv` is the function that takes as variable input `v` which we want to compute `A*v` and `C` is the fixed, known vector which we need for the assembly of `A`.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to allow the `LinearOperator` class to accept two inputs, one variable and one "fixed" like I can in MATLAB.
Is there a way to do the analogous operation in SciPy?  Alternatively, if anyone knows of a better way of inverting a large, dense matrix `(50000, 50000)` where the entries follow a pattern, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should have stated this information actually. The matrix is actually (in block form) `[A C; C^T 0]`, where `A` is `N x N` (`N` large) and `C` is `N x 3`, and the `0` is `3 x 3` and `C^T` is the transpose of `C`. This array `C` is the same array as the one mentioned above. The entries of `A` follow a pattern `A[i,j] = f(C[i] - C[j])`.

I wrote `mv(v,C)` to go row by row construct `A*v[i]` for `i=0,N`, by computing sum `f(C[i]-C[j)*v[j]` (actually, I do `numpy.dot(FC,v)` where `FC[j] = f(C[i]-C[j])` which works well). Then, at the end doing the computations for the `C^T` rows. I was hoping to eventually replace the large for loop with a `multiprocessing` call to parallelize the for loop, but that's a future thing to consider. I will also look into using Cython to speed up the computations.

Comment: You don't really need mv to accept two arguments, you could use a closure (or even `functools.partial`) instead: `make_mv = lambda c: lambda v: sum(f(c[i] - c[j])...` (but you'd write it using `def` so that it's readable) and probably the function should be in Cython or it may be too slow for such a big matrix.

Comment: Thank you! I think the lambda construct is exactly what I want. I can define mv2 = lambda v: mv(v,C) in my script, then feed mv2(v) into gmres. I will look into Cython, as my method is quite slow for the large matrices I want to work with.

Comment: Be careful because that's not a closure and will bite you at some point. Your `mv2` function will use whatever `C` is in scope, not the one that was in scope when you created the function. If you want `mv2` to refer to a particular `C`, you absolutely need one of the two methods above, and then `mv = make_mv(C)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very late, but if you're still interested...

Your A matrix must be very low rank since it's a nonlinearly transformed version of a rank-2 matrix. Plus it's symmetric. That means it's trivial to inverse: get the truncated eigenvalue decompostion with, say, 5 eigenvalues: A = U*S*U', then invert that: A^-1 = U*S^-1*U'. S is diagonal so this is inexpensive. You can get the truncated eigenvalue decomposition with [eigh](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html).

That takes care of A. Then for the rest: use the [block matrix inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion). Looks nasty, but I will bet you 100,000,000 prussian francs that it's 50x faster than the direct method you were using.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will definitely look into this, as any improvement over the direct method would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation (some years later than you) of trying to use more than one argument to **LinearOperator**, but for another problem. The solution I found was the use of global variables, to avoid passing the variables as arguments to the function.