# Scipy LinearOperator dtype unspecified

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am attempting to use Scipy's `gmres` command. My matrix is dense and large, so my plan was to use the `LinearOperator` command to return only the matrix vector product. Please see my previous question here [LinearOperator with Two Inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249593/scipy-linearoperator-with-multiple-inputs). With help from that question, I was able to build a `LinearOperator` object which successfully does the computation `A*x` where `A` is the matrix and `x` is the vector.

The problem is when I call `gmres`. I run the command:

```
x, info = scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres(A, b)
```

and it returns the error that the operator `A` has no `dtype`. This is true, as `A.dtype` returns an error. My problem is that I have no idea what to specify for `dtype`. When I construct my linear operator, there is an optional parameter to pass for `dtype`, but I do not know what to give it.
I tried passing `dtype='float64'` and that froze my IDE, so I suspect I'm wrong there.
Trying `dtype = None` just yields the default, where dtype is not defined.

I also tried simply defining `A` leaving `dtype` blank, and then typing `A.dtype = None`. This actually gives the attribute `A.dtype` and yields another error when calling `A`.

This seems to be linked to another problem, which is that the gmres seems to want a preconditioner given to it. I don't actually have a pre-conditioner I want to give it, so it tries to construct one and it tries to use the same dtype as A but, since A has no dtype attribute it errors out.  Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
A = sparse.scipy.linalg.linearoperator(shape = (n,n), matvec = mv, dtype = 'float64')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 393, in gmres
    A,M,x,b,postprocess = make_system(A,M,x0,b,xtype)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/utils.py", line 119, in make_system

M = LinearOperator(A.shape, matvec=psolve, rmatvec=rpsolve, dtype=A.dtype)
AttributeError: LinearOperator instance has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using the sparse module for dense matrix operations?

Comment: No, I would prefer not to, but I could only find it in the sparse library. There was a scipy.linalg.gmres, but it seems to either be deprecated or not showing up in my version of scipy. The documentation claims it works for sparse, dense or LinearOperator type matrices.

Comment: Note that there is no need to use LinearOperator, you can just directly pass the dense matrix to `gmres(a, b)`.

Comment: I cannot load the matrix directly because it takes up too much RAM for the computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is more of an extended comment than an answer.)

What version of scipy are you using?  I'm using scipy 0.13.0.  If I don't specify the dtype when I create the `LinearOperator`, I get the `dtype` error that you get.  But specifying `dtype='float64'` works for me:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator, gmres

In [3]: def mymatvec(v):
   ...:     a = np.array([[4,2,1],[2,2,1],[1,1,1]])
   ...:     return a.dot(v)
   ...: 

In [4]: A = LinearOperator((3,3), mymatvec, dtype='float64')

In [5]: b = np.array([1,2,3])

In [6]: gmres(A, b)
Out[6]: (array([-0.5, -0.5,  4. ]), 0)
```

Comment: I am using Scipy version 0.9.0. I unfortunately think I'm stuck with this version, as it is the version on the computer I plan on running this code on which I do not have the ability to install new versions on. When I add dtype='float64' and try calling A from the interpreter, my Python IDE completely freezes. I can add code if that would be helpful.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I run this in my Python IDE (Spyder), it freezes if I ever try calling A, but if I just execute from the command line python my_file.py it runs without a problem after setting it to dtype='float64'. Maybe the problem is now just with my IDE. I haven't confirmed yet its giving me the "right" result, but otherwise it looks like your suggestion works for me. Thanks!